# Multiple replacements within a matrix in a single line in R

Tags: r, matrix

Is there a way to do the following replacement in a single line in `R`? If possible, would it be more/less efficient?

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(100), ncol=10)

threshold <- 0.5

# Is there a single-line way to do the following in R
m[m < threshold] <- 0
m[m >= threshold] <- 1
```

I'm wondering if the `ifelse()` function can accommodate this, in the sense of *if < threshold then 0, else 1*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you want a vector of 1s and 0s, you could just reverse your condition, convert the logical values to integer, and create a new matrix with the same dimensions as `m`.

```
matrix(as.integer(m >= threshold), nrow(m))
```

You could also just change the matrix's mode.  Normally changing modes would be done in two lines, but you can do it in one with

```
`mode<-`(m >= threshold, "integer")
```

Additionally, as @nicola points out, the quick and dirty method is

```
(m >= threshold) + 0L
```

By adding the zero integer we coerce the entire matrix to integer.

A couple of others (thanks @Frank):

```
+(m >= threshold)
m[] <- m >= threshold
```

So basically, yes.  All these perform the task in one line and I can almost guarantee they are all faster than `ifelse()`.

Some benchmarks on a larger matrix (with the replacement method left out):

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(1e7), ncol=100)
threshold <- 0.5

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
    matrix = matrix(as.integer(m >= threshold), nrow(m)),
    mode = `mode<-`(m >= threshold, "integer"),
    plus0 = (m >= threshold) + 0L,
    unary = +(m >= threshold)
)

# Unit: milliseconds
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
# matrix 295.9292 315.4463 351.9149 351.8144 379.9840 453.4915   100
#   mode 163.2156 172.0180 208.9348 202.8014 232.4525 347.0616   100
#  plus0 170.2059 177.6111 202.3536 192.3516 223.8284 294.8367   100
#  unary 144.0128 150.2696 183.2914 173.4010 203.7955 382.2397   100
```

For the sake of completeness, here is a benchmark on the replacement method using `times = 1`.

```
microbenchmark(
    replacement = { m[] <- m >= threshold },
    times = 1
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  replacement 499.4005 499.4005 499.4005 499.4005 499.4005 499.4005     1
```

Comment: Also `(m>=threshold)+0L`.

Comment: @nicola If you're content with obscure coercions, might as well just do `+(m >= threshold)`

Comment: @Megatron I'd stress that just `m>=threshold` should be enough, since `TRUE` and `FALSE` internally are just 1 and 0 and can be used as such in basically any instance.

Comment: Richard, I think you're leaving out the most obvious one: `m[] <- m >= threshold` (which coerces per nicola's last comment).

Comment: Any idea which of these would be most efficient?

Comment: `m>=threshold`, if you are content of `TRUE` and `FALSE` instead of `1` and `0`.

Comment: @Megatron - No, but it wouldn't be difficult to benchmark.  Have you done it before?  `library(microbenchmark)`

Comment: @RichardScriven - Thanks - Looks like `+(m >= threshold)` is the fastest